# Loading custom u-boot script

Tags: partitioning, yocto, u-boot, nvidia-jetson

I've created an image (with Yocto and meta-tegra) and got a Jetson Nano devkit running with two rootfs that RAUC updating uses. I am currently (temporarily during testing) using the Jetson Nano devkit SPI flash to store the u-boot environment.

I have a script that I successfully got running on my device with [tftp](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootScripts). I've also *manually* typed in every line of my script to an environment variable, saved it and set `bootcmd` to run it. But if i want more than one device with this u-boot, i wouldn't want to manually type in the script for every device i make. But I also don't want a tftp server to be running at the side to be able to boot.

I want to run my script completely independent and automatically. So I've been thinking about having the script on a partition on it's own and get u-boot to load the script from there. But how do i tell u-boot to look for at script in the specific partition? Can i use `source SCRIPT_PARTITION_OFFSET`?

I've also seen that the standard boot.scr can be run from the u-boot shell. Where is this boot.scr located? I can't seem to find where it is created or where it is stored.

*****************************************************EDIT:*****************************************************
As a temporary solution I have put the boot script image into `/boot/` folder and set the u-boot to scan for scripts in the that folder on both rootfs and then run it if it can find it.

For this solution i still have to edit the u-boot env to make u-boot boot this custom way, so it is not a solution i can use in the long run. I might as well make a script to run *once* via tftp that will set `bootcmd` to be the entire boot script content.

Can i edit the u-boot source code with a patch that has my script in it's environment? - if so, how?

Comment: In `include/common` you'll probably find a header with your _default_ environment. You could edit that and rebuild. Remember you need to default your environment in uboot to see the change.

Comment: Thank you, I found something alike your comment suggests. The file `u-boot-tegra/include/config_distro_bootcmd.h` that contains the variable `distro_bootcmd` that is run by default by `bootcmd` at normal build. I've made a patch for that file that has the distro_bootcmd variable contain my script content. If it works, i will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, i was able to make a patch for `u-boot-tegra/include/config_distro_bootcmd.h` that has the variable `distro_bootcmd` set to my script content. When i then build my yocto image and boot up my Jetson Nano, i can see that the variable is in fact set.

This way should work for any u-boot and not just for Jetson Nano. Just find the bootcmd variable in the u-boot that runs at default boot and patch it.